# The app crashes when comes to the line "private TextView name = new TextView(this);"

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating a simple phone book.
I don`t know what is the problem.

I have two classes: MainActivity and Abonent; Abonent gives all the necessary info to MainActivity and then this info should be outputted to the screen, but when it comes to the line "private TextView name = new TextView(this);" of the Abonent class, the app crashes.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout main, submain;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams main_param, submain_param;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Initializing
        main = new LinearLayout(this);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        main.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.myblue));
        main_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(main, main_param);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Abonent abn = new Abonent("Kathrine", 0x7f020054 + i , "+38096" + i);
            submain= new LinearLayout(this);
            submain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            submain_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            submain_param.bottomMargin = 40;

            main.addView(abn.getName(), abn.name_param);

            submain.addView(abn.getIcon(), abn.icon_param);

            submain.addView(abn.getNumber(), abn.number_param);

            main.addView(submain, submain_param);

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Abonent extends MainActivity{
    public Abonent(String name, int iconId, String number){

        setName(name);
        setNumber(number);
        setIcon(iconId);
    }

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams name_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams icon_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams number_param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    private TextView name = new TextView(this);
    private ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
    private TextView number = new TextView(this);
    //private Button call = new Button(this);
    private SpannableString content;
    private void setName(String name){
        content = new SpannableString(name);
        content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
        this.name.setText(content);
        this.name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myblack));
        this.name.setTextSize(30);
        this.name_param.leftMargin = 40;
    }
    private void setNumber(String number){
        content = new SpannableString(number);
        content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
        this.number.setText(content);
        this.number.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myblack));
        this.number.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myblue));
        this.number.setTextSize(30);
        this.number_param.leftMargin = 40;
    }
    private void setIcon(int iconId){
        this.icon.setImageResource(iconId);
    }
    public TextView getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public TextView getNumber(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public ImageView getIcon(){
        return this.icon;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Abonent` should **not** extend `MainActivity`, or you should **not** make a `new Abonent` since it is an Activity class.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should call `super.onCreate` as the first thing in the `onCreate` method. Always. No exception.

Anyways, the error is because the references to `this` are not available to get the `Context` that is needed to create new Views in the way that you've done it.

You also do not need `Abonent extends MainActivity`, mostly because I don't think you understand what you are doing there.

---

If you are making a contact list for a phonebook, though, you want a ListView & ArrayAdapter, not a LinearLayout with dynamically added views.

For starters, I recommend you read [**Android ListView - Using a Custom ArrayAdapter**](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter). (Read from the top of the page, for more of an intro instead of diving into the code)

Answer (score 0):

The context/activity is not ready yet until `onCreate` is called. So don't try to instantiate them like that. Rather do that on `onCreate`